# Are there different Terms for "Synonyms" when distinguishing inflectable Words from particular inflected Forms?

Tags: terminology, synonymy

I am thinking of two slightly different concepts, both of which I would refer to as *synonymy*. As I would like to distinguish the concepts in a text, I am looking for two distinct words.

First, I will use the following two terms (and define them here, because I am not sure whether I am using the correct terminology here, either):

- A **word** consists of any number of inflected forms. It is like a full package of inflected forms, appropriate for its part of speech. For example, the word *building* is like a package that contains the various inflected forms of that word, namely *building* and *buildings*.
- An **inflected form** is (in its written form) just a single piece of text; for example, *building* is one inflected form, *buildings* is another.

Now, for the sake of this explanation, let us consider *building* and *edifice* as synonyms (disregarding any different nuances in their precise meanings).

This means:

1. The **word** *building* is a synonym of the **word** *edifice*.
2. The **inflected form** *building* is a synonym of the **inflected form** *edifice*.
3. The **inflected form** *buildings* is a synonym of the **inflected form** *edifices*.

Obviously, (1) describes a slightly different concept of synonymity compared to (2) and (3):

- (1) implies that each inflected form of *building* can be assumed to be synonymous with the equivalent inflected form of *edifice*, if such a form exists (some words can be only used in singular or in plural, for example).
- (2) and (3) say explicitly that *building* can be replaced with *edifice*, and that *buildings* can be replaced with *edifices*, respectively. However, they do not make any explicit statements about the synonymy relationship between the two "word packages".

The different concepts could be paraphrased as *synonymy with respect to words* and *synonymy with respect to inflected forms*, but **is there any more concise term?**

Comment: Except of course that building and edifice aren't synonyms ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call a **word** is actually called a [**lexeme**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme), what you call **inflected forms** are actually called [**lemmas**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)). The difference between the lexeme-to-lexeme synonymity and the lemma-to-lemma synonymity is actually the point of your question, but I am afraid your question cannot be answered, for the former and the latter are phenomena of different levels, it is like comparing whether 10 fingers are more important than 2 hands.

Synonyms can be of different kinds, the ones of your (1) kind are semantic synonyms, it is the similarity of the lexical meaning of the two words that makes them synonyms. The ones of the (2) and (3) kinds are not only lexical, but also grammatical synonyms, they share not only the lexical meaning, but also the grammar form.

Comment: Could that mean that (ignoring for a moment how well those terms can be understood by a general audience) *synonymous lexemes* and *synonymous lemmas* are the terms I am looking for?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Actually, yes. Only note, that lexemes are synonymous in a bit different way than lemmas are synonymous, in the former case the synonymity is just lexical, in the latter one it is both lexical and grammatical.

Comment: I don't think "lemma" is the word you want there. As explained in the wikipedia page you linked to, "lemma" refers to only one form of any particular lexeme- whichever one you choose to use as the label to talk about the lexeme as a whole. The individual morphological forms are generically just called "forms".

Comment: 'Surface form' and 'wordform' are also common terms for the OP's 'inflected form', especially when distinguishing between surface forms and lexemes (and often bases and roots as well, just to complicate things!) The root 'build', for example, can be conceived of as a package containing multiple packages, one of which is the package (i.e. lemma) 'building'.